# Solve conflict between Ubuntu libcv2.1 and ROS libopencv2.3

Tags: ros, opencv, ubuntu, rosdeb, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a recent update to OpenCV in ROS electric (as a system-wide package pulled in by ros-electric-vision-opencv) causes a conflict with the default Ubuntu library libcv2.1 (+libcvaux2.1 libhighgui2.1). With the electric apt-repository it is not possible to "apt-get upgrade" for all packages without removing the Ubuntu libraries. This will also uninstall third-party software which depends on the Ubuntu libs such as the video editing program "kdenlive" and its "frei0r-plugins".

The conflict must have happened in a recent update to vision-opencv as there was no problem before. Where lies the exact source of the problem, and how could it be fixed? Or is this just a temporary glitch in the apt repository? I feel like a ROS package should never conflict with a default system package on a supported platform. I wouldn't want to decide between the one usable video editing tool in Linux and future electric updates.

The behavior was observed on Ubuntu 11.04 and 10.04 (LTS).

**Edit, more details:**
Updating ros-electric-desktop-full to 1.0.0-s1319593787~natty will upgrade libopencv2.3 from 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~natty to 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-5~natty. The former works fine, while the latter conflicts with Ubuntu's libcv2.1 (version 2.1.0-3ubuntu1).

---

**Update 2:** Given that this is a bug in the packaging of OpenCV (as it looks from the comments and replies), where would a ticket go? OpenCV trunk upstream? ROS package management?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11698/solve-conflict-between-ubuntu-libcv2.1-and-ros-libopencv2.3/) by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5904 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2011-11-10**:
I'm getting the same issue too on ROS electric with 10.04. I feel like this issue came up before and it was fixed earlier but it's broken again now. Not sure what to do...

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-10-27**:
I added more details about the affected versions. Is this an error in the packaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The conflict now seems to be resolved with the latest update to the debs:

```
sudo apt-get install libcv2.1 ros-electric-vision-opencv libopencv2.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcv2.1 is already the newest version.
libopencv2.3 is already the newest version.
ros-electric-vision-opencv is already the newest version.
```

Package: libopencv2.3   Version: 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty

Package: ros-electric-vision-opencv   Version: 1.6.8-s1321009674~natty

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3